Set of all Matrices generated via Addition/Subtraction and Scalar/Matrix Multiplication from Generator Set
Given a set of matrices over a field with algebraic closure, how can the set of matrices generated via addition/subtraction and scalar multiplication as well as matrix multiplication be characterised?
The generator matrices are arbitrary and thus do not necessarily include the identity. Most of the available results assume identity matrices or matrix invertibility - is there any structural framework without those prerequisites?
For example, is there any criterion to conclude that the full space of matrices for the respective dimension can be obtained?
